# Create a jar file containing both .java and .class files

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a Java project with maven. I generated a jar file with the following steps: 
Go to maven window which has my project -> Lifecycle->install. Double click on install. 
It generates a jar file `Lab1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` under the target folder. 
I extracted the jar file it only contained the `.class` files. 
How could I build a jar that contains both the source code `.java` files and bytecode `.class` files?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want this? The normal way is to only have `.class` files in a JAR, and if you really need to distribute sources, then create a separate -sources.jar file.

Comment: Can I simply run the command to generate jar file - `jar cf jar-file input-file(s)`. Could that cause any issue. This is a requirement for the assignment to include all .class and .java files in the jar. so I could simply specify all the .class and .java file in the command line and get the bundled jar

Comment: I have some Junit5 code too. In that case should I bundle the jar with Junit5 libraries too? Or simply the class and .java files would be enough? Because otherwise I think as it uses Junit5 API. It may cause problems. What are your thoughts on this?